# my app consume high CPU

Tags: android, cpu-usage

My app is composed by four tab : a webview, and three view with some text/edittext, ...
The problem is my app consume a lot of CPU and I don't understand why, and one of the main problem is when the app is onPause (the user use the home button), my app still use CPU (arround 20%, or even more !) and is battery consuming.

I don't understand what use so much CPU, so I have two questions :

1. How can I know exactly (with eclipse) the process (method, activity...) which use too much CPU ?
2. How can I "freeze" with 0 CPU consumption my app when the user press the home button (I suppose is in the onPause method, I try with a finish(), it's work but when the user go back to my app, he get a FC).

Thanks a lot !

EDIT :

Seems my webview consume the CPU. How can i do to stop this webview during onPause without destroy the webview object ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the solution :

THe javascript content in the webview was the problem. To solve that :

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    /* pause timer of the webview, if not, high CPU during on pause */
    page.pauseTimers();
}
```

and on Resume,

```
public void onResume() {  
    /* reactive timer */
    super.onResume();
    page.resumeTimers();
}
```